# How to align favicons in a row under span tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two favicons under a `span` tag for a media query in css but having trouble. I tried to put the media query as `display: block;` which is moving the two icons under the span, which is good but then it's moving the second icon under the first one

final output should look like this below once going to 560px screen size. I've attached a snippet

```
   Check Us Out!
   icon_1 icon_2
```

```css
#social_media{
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #270627, #3e0742, #550660, #6b0481, #8104a4, #921bb6, #a32cc9, #b43bdc, #c553e0, #d46ae4, #e27fe9, #ee95ee);
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}


#row_media{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#social_media span{
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Impact, fantasy;
  color: white;
}

#social_media a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#social_media i{
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  #social_media i{
    display: block;

  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="social_media">
      <div class="row" id="row_media">
        <div class="col">
          <span>Check Us Out!</span>
          <a href="test.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please make the fiddle correct by using proper style imports, also add a imge how the final ui should look like

Answer (score 0):

```css
#social_media{
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #270627, #3e0742, #550660, #6b0481, #8104a4, #921bb6, #a32cc9, #b43bdc, #c553e0, #d46ae4, #e27fe9, #ee95ee);
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}


#row_media{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#social_media span{
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Impact, fantasy;
  color: white;
}

#social_media a{
  text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
}

#social_media i{
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  #social_media i{
    display: block;

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="social_media">
      <div class="row" id="row_media">
        <div class="col">
          <span>Check Us Out!</span>
          <div class = "row">
          <a href="test.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram">In</i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook">Fa</i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a solution to your problem. I placed the fontawesome icons in `<div class="icons">` and then added a flex setting to `<div>`.

```css
#social_media{
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #270627, #3e0742, #550660, #6b0481, #8104a4, #921bb6, #a32cc9, #b43bdc, #c553e0, #d46ae4, #e27fe9, #ee95ee);
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }
  
  i {
      color: whitesmoke;
  }

  .icons {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  
  #row_media{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #social_media span{
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Impact, fantasy;
    color: white;
  }
  
  #social_media a{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #social_media i{
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
    #social_media i{
      display: block;
  
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="social_media">
        <div class="row" id="row_media">
          <div class="col">
            <span>Check Us Out!</span>
              <div class="icons">
                <a href="test.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

TO align the icons use the flex property this would align the elements side by side. Here I have used the flex property in the Css and later applied it to my HTML code. I have provided the Css and Html code for your reference

CSS

```css
#social_media{
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #270627, #3e0742, #550660, #6b0481, #8104a4, #921bb6, #a32cc9, #b43bdc, #c553e0, #d46ae4, #e27fe9, #ee95ee);
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}


#row_media{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-decoration {
    width: 50%;
      float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    flex: 1;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#social_media span{
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Impact, fantasy;
  color: white;
}

#social_media a{
  text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
}

#social_media i{
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  #social_media i{
    display: block;

  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="social_media">
      <div class="row" id="row_media">
        <div class="icon-decoration">
          <span>Check Us Out!</span>
          <div class = "row">
          <a href="test.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram">In</i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook">Fa</i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```